# Как записать в массив значения из переменной string

Tags: java

Суть такова: у меня есть переменная string c большим количеством значений, разделенных пробелом, как записать их в массив ?

```
String gg = "-46988 -68551 803 14813 61177 30323 -48803 -9078 58878 -23942 -20357 6129 -4614 11981 42568 45595 -45832 -48468 244 -75071 35312 -14668 14922 -51287 -38736 79941 -72017 40862 63925 52194 74910 -63063 63642 -4287 31750 44819 -53963 62946 -44258 -75085 -40995 15384 11044 34390 -52635 -26387 -14 -18467 5145 -79770 -13538 -39542 -14439 -78616 -10829 26824 -78674 -2847 -12313 65250 -30653 -17403 -77812 -47010 58309 33938 77809 -75653 16885 -46449 -70738 55889 48934 20306 10280 76299 73919 -69734 -22168 -936 -69505 44294 39522 -3944 45677 -51307 -57119 47003 25846 10567 32253 75193 73163 34441 -51817 51473 -11621 -54008 55820 -74736 -20458 65081 61153 -51523 5387 -8567 -55223 -694 1698 2608 78370 12193 -33097 37892 -71750 -67419 66584 -48870 59583 12431 41697 11837 7624 34860 -33722 35806 6334 34656 61798 -17845 39919 -38660 -32764 21072 -10183 52623 -67494 14593 -28070 14203 -62798 -29699 -53603 -15896 -71807 -45353 -3316 74777 -14224 -23733 7208 -52527 68103 -65168 62333 -45619 50638 -11332 69037 32436 50822 28956 73776 -61941 -29971 -16407 70682 -17466 78185 -37388 76737 -64613 12912 -56865 -509 21105 -22219 76174 15883 43556 -27558 -56909 71029 -39454 -42077 53363 -5073 -71439 -37969 -16036 40997 -67146 -67079 34773 -49088 -17051 -61634 -58406 45483 -63448 -15794 42220 -48061 77118 65355 31429 18224 -36864 27603 -45893 -73307 -79954 -22803 77722 -39409 15120 51085 35517 23680 -66884 -60519 -15323 -54030 -47599 -60550 -23119 15350 -42184 -1525 -19166 -25633 62681 -56946 6305 59800 -71590 -42265 -1976 -28455 65337 32130 -21762 65383 -70672 -24040 -54026 24447 -52955 61490 -31873 -39839 -79028 32804 -13870 -46628 52254 43011 48722 -69930 -38513 -50444 -15563 -55831 -27390 70742 -76031 -18981 -51523 1992 32564 -66185 -45878 -69198 79197 -36550 -13239 -54828 67896 13805 -73338 -43976 53966 -72367 68827 -39903 -38995 41081 -76892 -70272 51151 -35405 -40717 -44411 -11237 11893 -53669 -7269 72912 -25192 74723";
```

После преобразовать в целочисленный массив.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так:

```
        String[] arr = gg.split(" ");
        int[] arrInt = new int[arr.length];
        int i = 0;
        for(String str : arr){
            try {
                arrInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(str);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("str = " + str);
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: Еще вопрос, как его преобразовать в целочисленный ?

Comment: добавил код в ответ

Answer (score 2):

gg.split(" ");
Кажись так :-)
.............